# how to create credentials.json for google calendar integration

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

In the past i have created an application that created google calendar events. I am attempting to re-create that and everything is working great until i need to get the 'credentials.json' file. I cant remember how to get that file created, and nothing on the internet seems to be able to do it without using google cloud.

Wondering if there is a way to do this without using the google-cloud?
I am using C# and the 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3' package.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: No, You can't get it the credentials.json is the file which connects google api and your application. You can't get it

Comment: How do i generate it then?

Comment: From the Google cloud itself

Comment: You need to get the service account credentials

Comment: It depends on which type of application you are working with [Installed app](https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ) ,  [web app](https://youtu.be/pBVAyU4pZOU) or [service account](https://youtu.be/asrCdWFrF0A)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think you can do it without the help of Google Cloud. (Same as what Infinite Coders mentioned in the comments)

Follow the [.NET quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/dotnet) here for the complete list of steps you need to take to integrate google calendar to your script.

The quickstart above includes the credential creation which you can visit [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials) directly.

Answer (score 0):

To get a credentials.json file your application needs to be registered with google on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

This is how google knows who is using their apis and authorization server.  There is no way to automate creating the credentials.json it must be manually created.

Depending upon which type of application you are working with will define how it is created [Installed app](https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ) ,  [web app](https://youtu.be/pBVAyU4pZOU) or [service account](https://youtu.be/asrCdWFrF0A)